# probleme with a file.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, apk

I want to put "code" in APK but when I click on "export signed application package" it moves the window except that I cannot put next because there is an error message which says "Project has compilation errors" and my "AndroidManifest.xml" file has a red logo next to it. I can't find any solution on the internet, please help me;)

Comment: Did you open AndroidManifest.xml and look for the errors?

Comment: Did you look at the _Problems_ view in Eclipse? From the Eclipse menu bar choose: **Window > Show View > Problems**

Comment: they say it's the name that has a problem and in the code of the file, at line 15 "android: value =" @ integer / google_play_services_version "/>" it puts a red cross on me